# Calculate previous day using joda time

Tags: java, date, jodatime

I am calculating time based on Hawaii timezone.I have test scenario where my current date is **2017-01-01T10:52:07.656-10:00** (January 1). When I try to get previous date using .minusDays(1) I get date as **2016-12-31T12:52:07.656-08:00** (December 31).

Now for previous date when I try to format in *MM/DD/YYYY*. I get output as *12/366/2016* instead of *12/31/2016*

My code:

```
    DateTime dt4 = new DateTime("2017-01-01T10:52:07.656-10:00");
    System.out.println("Given Date:"+ dt4);
    DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/DD/YYYY");
    System.out.println("Given Date After Date format: "+fmt.print(dt4));

    DateTime previousDay = dt4.minusDays(1);
    System.out.println("Previous Day: "+ previousDay);
    System.out.println("Previous Date After Date format: "+fmt.print(previousDay));
```

O/p:
        Given Date:    2017-01-01T12:52:07.656-08:00
        Given date After Date format: 01/01/2017
        Previous Day: 2016-12-31T12:52:07.656-08:00
        Previous Date After Date format: 12/366/2016

Comment: probably you need `dd` or `d` instead of `DD`

Answer (score 2):

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

You get 366 because 2016 year has 366 days and you chosen the last one.
The Capital D is for Day in year, what i think you want is d lower case for day in month.

If you scroll down you will see some examples that can help you.